# Parameter undefined in function call

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vuex

In my Vuex store im calling some functions in the action section.

the code looks like this:

```
 actionSignUp({ commit, dispatch }, form) {
  commit("setStatus", "loading")
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(form.email, form.password)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.user.uid)
      console.log("Successfull registered")
      dispatch("actionCreateUserDocument", form, response.user.uid)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      commit("setStatus", "failure")
      commit("setError", error.message)
    })
},

actionCreateUserDocument({ dispatch }, form, uid) {
  console.log(uid)
  usersCollection.doc(uid).set({
    email: form.email,
    name: form.name,
    courses: []
  })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Document successfully written!");
      dispatch("actionFetchUserProfile", uid)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
},
```

in the `actionSignUp` function I call `console.log(response.user.uid`. Here I'm getting the right value. But when I call `dispatch("actionCreateUserDocument", form, response.user.uid)` the `uid` is undefinded in the `actionCreateUserDocument()` function.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you're passing multiple arguments.

Vuex store allows the following:

```
dispatch(type: string, payload?: any, options?: Object): Promise<any>
dispatch(action: Object, options?: Object): Promise<any>
```

Therefore, Vuex Store treats your argument `response.user.uid` as options.

You have to refactor it to something like:

```
dispatch("actionCreateUserDocument", {
  form,
  userId: response.user.uid
})
```

Comment: So if I habe multiple options i habe to bundle them to an object?

Comment: Yeah. According to the documentation on https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#dispatch dispatch takes up to three arguments. 

```
dispatch(type: string, payload?: any, options?: Object): Promise<any>
dispatch(action: Object, options?: Object): Promise<any>
```

examples:

```
dispatch('my_type');
dispatch('my_type', { a: 1, b: 2});
dispatch({
  type: 'my_type',
  a: 1,
  b: 2
});
```

Comment: hmm `dispatch("actionCreateUserDocument", { form, userId: response.user.uid })` isnt working for me either, its still undefined.

Comment: you've also patched the `actionCreateUserDocument` function to something like `actionCreateUserDocument({ dispatch }, { form, userId })`?